# PhpUnit simple command to show less results

Tags: testing, phpunit

At the moment if I run `./phpunit -c ../app` I might get output like:

```
PHPUnit 3.7.88 by Sebastian Begmann.

Configuration read from /var/www/site/app/Symfony/app/phpunit.xml

FFFSS....

Time 7.9 seconds, Memory: 55.00Mb

There were 4 failures:

.. lists the failures

FAILURES!
Tests: 9, Assertions: 64, Failures: 4, Skipped: 2.
```

This is good in some cases, like if I want to run the tests myself. But for some cases (automated testing), I just want to run the tests and know whether they all passed or not (maybe send an email if there were failures).

So my question, is there a simple command I can use like `./phpunit -c ../app --short` which will just return whether all tests passed or not.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redirect the command output to /dev/null and check the command exit code:

```
./phpunit -c ../app >/dev/null 2>&1
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "TESTS PASSED!"
fi
```

Comment: Thanks. I can't see it documented anywhere online but you are indeed correct, the exit code is 1 if any of the unit tests fail. If all tests pass, then 0 is the exit code.